NaCl melting temperature is low if you consider cohesive its energy
NaCl melting temperature is 1074k.
NaCl cohesive energy is 7.9eV.
Carbon melting temperature is 3915k.
Carbon cohesive energy is 7.4eV.
As you can see NaCl melting temperature is lower than the carbon one even though the cohesive energy is bigger. These thing seems frequent in ionic crystals.
I don't understand why, I believed a material melt when its thermal energy becomes comparable with the binding energy. Can you give an explanation?
My personal guess is that it due to ionization energy, but I don't understand it properly

Well, you have not considered the binding energies in the liquids. The ionic interactions in NaCl don’t care a lot about being in a crystal vs a liquid.
